# Bash - variable exponents when raising power

Tags: linux, bash, bc

This works

```
answer=$(echo "2^3" | bc)
$ 8
```

However, this does not.  Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar=$(echo "4-1" | bc)    
answer=$(echo "2^$myvar" | bc)
echo $answer
```

When I run this with 'set -x', this is the output

```
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '|'
./test.sh: line 3: 'myvar=(echo "4-1" | bc)
++ echo '2^'
++ bc
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
+ answer=
+ echo
```

I want to stick with bc, but can't figure out how to pass a var as an exponent.

Comment: They both work for me.

Comment: Why do you need to use `bc`? `bash` has a built-in exponent operator: `answer=$((2 ** myvar))`

Comment: Please show a log of you running `myvar=3; answer=$(echo "2^$myvar" | bc); echo "$answer"` and getting a result other than 8. Which is to say -- the claim here is hard to believe, and without a demonstration that you tested your exact reproducer (as opposed to deriving it from your real code but not checking that the problem still existed), I decline to believe it.

Comment: Does it maybe say `: not found` or `$'\r': command not found` or `illegal character: ^M`?

Comment: @Adam, if you mean that *nothing* displays (as opposed to conveying that your comment got cut off), use `set -x` to generate a log of commands run by your shell -- and edit that log into the question itself.

Comment: @Adam: ...that is to say, copy-and-paste the following, *exactly*, into your shell, and then copy-and-paste the exact result (which will be sent to stderr) into a code-formatted block in your question: `(set -x; myvar=3; answer=$(echo "2^$myvar" | bc); echo "$answer")`

Comment: I edited my question. I realized that I forgot that "myvar" was a result from another operation of bc.  This is the scenario that doesn't work

Comment: @Adam, ...to repeat myself yet again, edit it with a `set -x` log. For example, [here's one](https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/bb15f0f74e8eb6ce858d36094eb816e2) logging the invocation and output of `(set -x; myvar=$(echo "4-1" | bc); answer=$(echo "2^$myvar" | bc); echo "$answer")`, and thereby showing this code to work when I run it; given such a log, we could figure out exactly where it's breaking for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Here's the full program (including your addition):

    !/bin/bash
    set -x
    myvar=$(echo "4-1" | bc)
    answer=$(echo "2^$myvar" | bc)
    echo $answer

When I run this, here is the result:

    ./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '|'
    ./test.sh: line 3: 'myvar=(echo "4-1" | bc)'
    ++ echo '2^'
    ++ bc
    (standard_in) 2: syntax error
    + answer= 
    + echo

Comment: `myvar=(echo "4-1" | bc)` is not `myvar=$(echo "4-1" | bc)`. You're missing the `$` on the `$()` expansion (in your real code but not in the question, which is why we ask folks to **test the exact code in the question before posting**.

Comment: Might I ask how you're running this? If it's getting to your shell through some evaluation or templating layer that's stripping the `$` that the syntax error reports to be missing, there's our bug.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I just edited my main question above, so that it accurately reflects the script and the problem

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I'm just running the script from the terminal like this:

$ ./test.sh

Comment: If you create a new file copy-and-pasting your code from your StackOverflow question back out to disk (via a programmer's editor, or `cat >yourscript <<'EOF'` and putting an EOF at the end of the code -- note the quotes, so expansions aren't run), you get the same error? (It's conceivable you could have hidden characters in your real code messing things up; copying back from the question means that you're really running with the same thing we are).

Comment: btw, if you'd included the syntax error in your question in the first place, it wouldn't have taken so much of our time and yours to draw details out. In the future, please try to make sure error messages are included in your questions. And consider running through http://shellcheck.net/, which can catch syntax errors (such as this one) before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact error you would get if your script were **actually**:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar=(echo "4-1" | bc)    
answer=$(echo "2^$myvar" | bc)
echo $answer
```

Note the `$` missing in the first `$()`